# Behavior when sorting an array with multiple objects in it in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have this collection.

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": [
      {
        "family": "A",
        "given": [ "Z" ],
        "use": 0
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": [
      {
        "family": "Z",
        "given": [ "A" ],
        "use": 1
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

I naturally understand the behavior of the following sort on name.family.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $sort: {
      "name.family": 1
    }
  }
])
```

However, I do not fully understand how mongo behaves when sorting on the entire name array as in [playGround](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vjDZW_WpPGg).

In this case, is it sorted in the first place?

If sorted, how and where does mongoDB refer to the array?

Thanks.

Comment: I believe that I've answered your question below. Can you check and accept please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> TLDR; In this instance, Mongo `Recursively compares key-value pairs in the order that they appear within the BSON object.`

All info from docs: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/bson-type-comparison-order/

Mongo sorts in the following order:

```
1) MinKey (internal type)
2) Null
3) Numbers (ints, longs, doubles, decimals)
4) Symbol, String
5) Object
6) Array
7) BinData
8) ObjectId
9) Boolean
10) Date
11) Timestamp
12) Regular Expression
13) MaxKey (internal type)
```

So whilst `name` is an array, the item in that array is an object, so I believe that it:
`Recursively compare key-value pairs in the order that they appear within the BSON object.` (From docs linked above)

In your playground example, `{$sort:{"name":1}}`, the first field of the first entry is 'family' therefore the first sort operation is executed on that field for that document.

If you change the first object so that it has a different first field:

```
{
  "use": 0,
  "family": "A",
  "given": [
    "Z"
  ]
}
```

The order sort will use the use key in ascending order give you a different result.

Comment: I think this answer is mostly correct in that it talks about how whole (sub)objects are compared. However I think it leaves out the aspect of the question which is that `name` is an array. In the two sample documents each array only has a single entry so it doesn't matter. But assuming that there will be more entries in some situations, then [array sort behavior](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/release-notes/3.6-compatibility/#array-sort-behavior) is also relevant. It will select the smallest (or largest) array entry to sort on - [example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fiUCHTLzNIB)